# Notify Android and iPhone users with a horizontal bar on my website to install my app from Google Play Store or Appstore

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, web

How could I notify Android and iPhone users by using a horizontal bar on my website in order to recommend them to install my mobile application from Google Play Store or Appstore just like vouchercloud.de does (if you open the website with your mobile phone).

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the user's browser's User Agent:
For iPhone, it will look like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1C25 Safari/419.3
```

For iPad:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10
```

For Android:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-us; T-Mobile myTouch 3G Slide Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

You can check [this](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) for a complete list of known user agents.

To detect the User Agent, you can use this (add the devices you want in the conditions ie:iPad, android...).:
**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
 (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
   if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1) window.location = "http://iphone.yoursite.com/";
}
</script>
```

or
**PHP**

```
<?php
if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod'))
 {
  header('Location: http://yoursite.com/iphone');
  exit();
}
?>
```

or
**.HTACCESS**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*iPad.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ipad.yourdomain.com [R=301]
```

---

**Edit:** If you need a wordpress plugin, [have a look here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/user-agent).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I thought more of something ready made, a wordpress plugin or something.

Comment: You never said that you were using wordpress ;)

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to User-Agent related plugins.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, include a special meta tag with your app's ID. The system will automatically find the app and display the popup.

See Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html